# Hook with setwindowhookex

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I need help with this hook I am learning about hooks and I am doing one easy example to learn more about setwindowshookex of microsoft.
The first thing I am trying to include different control keys like ctrl, enter, etc I have tried this code:

```
if( wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN ){
           switch (wParam)
                       {
                           case VK_SHIFT:

                               qDebug() << "prueba";

                               break;

                           default:
                               break;
                       }
       }
```

Obviously didnt work. So i can do comparing but i prefer to include some type to check control key separated. At the same i am trying to include something to separate when i using different applications like notepad for learning.

Comment: The combination of `if (wParam==...)` and `switch(wParam)` inside does not make sense. You already know the value of `wParam` at this point, the `case` with another value can never be reached. Maybe you meant to check two different variables? What kind of function is this anyway? Is this your [`KeyboardProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way you check for modifier keys in a keyboard hook function is using GetKeyState, e.g.

```
LRESULT DLL_CALL KeyboardFunc (int nCode, WPARAM  wParam, LPARAM  lParam)
{
   ...

   if (nCode < 0)
      return (CallNextHookEx (hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));

   if (nCode == HC_NOREMOVE)
      return (CallNextHookEx (hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));

   switch (wParam)
   {
      case VK_F12 :

         // Check for modifier keys:

         if ((GetKeyState (VK_CONTROL) & iHiOrder) &&   // ctrl key
             (GetKeyState (VK_SHIFT)   & iHiOrder) &&   // shift key
             (GetKeyState (VK_MENU)    & iHiOrder)      // Alt  key
         {
         }
```

where HiOrder is a const SHORT value with the high-order bit set.